# adding and removing values in text fields set model to empty string ("") instead of null

Tags: angular, c#-2.0, angular11, jsonparser

I have text box bind with number filed in my Angular 11 Application, the form initializes with null value for this field and hence the text box shows nothing that is empty.

```
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control currency"
                   id="totalPersons"
                   name="totalPersons"
                   [(ngModel)]="model.totalPersons"
                   #totalPersons="ngModel"
                   (ngModelChange)="onValidateChange()"
                   (blur)="onValidateChange()"
                   oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'');"
                   [allowNegativeNumbers]="false" 
                   mask="separator.0" 
                   thousandSeparator="," 
                   maxlength="5"
                   required>
```

No when I click on save button I send modal to my save function, for totalPersons I get null values which is expected and my server side(C# API) has Nullable long field for totalPersons, till this point everything works fine.

Now if I type some number in textbox and them remove it (ie. set text box back top empty) and try to save it angular sends "" instead of null for totalPersons which results in JSON parsing error as server side has nullable long variable its it cannot parse ""

is there any way to handle this?

client Side variable

> totalPersons : number;

Server side variable

> public long? TotalPersons{ get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are putting the value there yourself

`oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'');"`

maybe you could add a check?

`oninput="this.value= this.value ? this.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'') : null;"`

Comment: looks like this is the problem, but the solution is not working after adding check the behavior is same, still sets empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's known issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45317

The stackblitz link given shows it's an issue even if there's no oninput or something.